# Find query shows all the list of courses and related information but while using th findById(id) ,it is unable to find the course

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Find query shows all the list of courses and related information but while using th findById(id) ,it is unable to find the course.

```
async function getCourse() {
    const course = await Course.find({});
    console.log(course);
}
getCourse()

async function updateCourse(id) {
    const course = await Course.findById(id);
    if (!course) return console.log("course not found");

    course.name = 'sagar';
    course.author = 'sagar';
    const result = await course.save();
    console.log(result);
}
updateCourse('5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e');
```

Comment: Is course empty or is a error thrown? Please paste the output of the script as show in terminal. Probably console.log(course)

Comment: { tags: [ 'aspnet', 'backend' ],
    _id: 5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e,
    date: 2018-01-24T21:42:59.605Z,
    name: 'ASP.NET MVC Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    isPublished: true,
    price: 15,
    __v: 0 } ]
course not found

Comment: The thing was a hash take 64 bits and I limit that to 50